# Confused in how to apply foreign key concept in my scenario

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database table called as Receipt, as follows:

[image]

The columns

- payment
- invoice
- custom_field
- organization

being separate tables

The constraint is that **for each receipt there can't be more than one of any from the above**. Which means for each receipt there will be one payment entry, one invoice entry, one custom_field and organization entry.

Now I think that I can get rid of all the column names mentioned above and instead associate _id as the primary key for my receipt table and same _id as the foreign key for all other tables.

In the above structure I am also confused as to how should I generate unique values for - payment - invoice - custom_field - organization if I go with the above structure. However if I chose to go with the later the primary and foreign key will be auto generated and unique. I am also concerned about editing. Is there anything helpful you can suggest?

Below is my structure:

[image]

Comment: maybe from my bad english I couldnt understand what you want exactly so If you can answer the following : what do you mean by being separate tables ? what are teh roles of those columns ? payment
invoice
custom_field
organization  you can refer those column to another table by id ( many to many )

Comment: you can refer to receipt table by id , if receipt has id = 1 , it will refer to user by id and paymnet and invoice id = 1 , thats your foriegn key

Comment: The roles of those columns are foreign keys, but I can get rid of them and assign my primary key as the foreign key for all these tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jordi is right, he got the right point. Only I don't think a many-many relationship applies to the original question, as it says "there **can't** be more than one..."

> The constraint is that for each receipt there cant be more than one of
>   any from the above. Which means for each receipt there will be one
>   payment entry, one invoice entry, one custom_field and organization
>   entry.

So, for each Receipt:

- One payment.
- One Invoice.
- One custom field
- and so on for as many 'extension' to the receipt table as you need.

If I understand correctly, you could in pure theory put all of those columns into one single "big" table with many columns, which would of course be ugly and bad in practice for other reasons which would be off-topic. But note that if you had one only table, you would also have the same primary key for everything, which is something you seem to have asked, but is also something you probably don't really want.

If you want to denormalize such 'one only big table' into receipt, invoices, customfields and so on... then the receipt table will have a primary key (let say 'ID') as well as any 'extension' and child table will have their primary key (let say 'ID' too).

So we go:

Receipt.ID, Invoice.ID, CustomFields.ID, Payment.ID and so on...

Keep in mind that all of those ids are on their own in relation to Receipt. Invoice.ID and Receipt.ID are **not in any way required to be the same**.

What you need to 'bind' any one of those children to its parent 'Receipt' is a dedicated column (let say 'ReceiptID') which is foreign-keyed to Receipt.ID.

Now as a last step, if you define an UNIQUE KEY or UNIQUE INDEX on ReceiptID in children tables, it will work to ensure that you will have at most 1 payment, at most 1 invoice etc for any given receipt.

If, for example, in the future you ever need to get more than one custom field for your receipts, or more than one payment information, you simply alter that UNIQUE constraint in customfield table into a simple non-unique INDEX and you are done.

I can't post images because of low reputation.
I hope I was able to make my point clear.

Comment: I see Jordi noticed himself... I leave my answer there as I hope it may further clarify.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, thanks mate. So Ideally I can use the receipt._id as my Primary and Foreign key with a unique constraint and Cascade on delete

Answer (score 2):

*The constraint is that for each receipt there **can't** be more than one of any from the above.*

My fault because fast reading.

## UPDATE: ONE-TO-MANY

What you have here is a [`ONE-TO-MANY relationship`](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/), so a simple receipt can have from `0` (or `1`?? is mandatory each other table is related with `receipt`??) to `N` related `users`, `payment`, `organization` etc...

**NOTE:** *if you can only have a single receipt for each user: `1` to `1` you will need a [`ONE-TO-ONE relationship`](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/)*.

**How to solve it?**
You ave to change your vision, you have the foreign keys in the `receipt` table, and you must have foreign keys in the **other tables**:

```
user
|-- id
|-- email
|-- other attributes
|-- receipt_id   // foreign key refering to a single receipt.
```

then your user table will have extra field,

```
user_id email     .....   receipt_id
1       a@a.com   others  1
2       b@b.com   others  1
3       c@c.com   others  2
```

and you can perform your selects like:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE receipt_id = 1
```

output:

```
1       a@a.com   others  1
2       b@b.com   others  1
```

**JOIN QUERY** (select receipt and get all users relateds):

```
SELECT * from receipt r JOIN user u where r.id = u.receipt_id;
```

## MANY-TO-MANY

That means you need a join table to map the [many-to-many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Let's explain with user:

One recipe can be refering several users (in real words, various users can access to this recipe, or various users made this recipe).

You will need a table recipe_users with just 2 fields both **FOREIGN KEYS**:

```
recipe_users
|---- recipe_id    // FK of recipe table
|---- user_id      // FK of user table
```

Then you can refer one recipe with various users

```
recipe_id    user_id
1            1
1            2 
1            3
```

Or have as many recipes as you want for each user,

```
recipe_id    user_id
1            1
2            1 
3            1
```

Comment: Thanks man, but this is the local DB structure and I will only have one user logged into my system at one instance. So I am not considering a multiple user base. What I am concerned for here is the Primary Key and Foreign key being the same.

Comment: i think you didn't get the point, read carefully, this is about table relation, nothing related with how many users connected in your application... also... what you mean with *Primary Key and Foreign key being the same*?? this does not have much sense... you don't have to care if two tables have same number_id...

Comment: Yes I get the relation you mention, But why do I require separate values and columns, when the _id feild can do it for me - _id can be the primary key for my Receipt table and the same _id can be the foreign key for my invoice table as there will be no more than one invoice associated with one receipt. This is the confusion I am talking about.

Comment: sorry... I misunderstood your question... :) check my update please

Comment: Yes this is what I meant :)